# Can you play Diablo 1 online with the HD mod?

Tags: diablo, diablo-1-hd

[High Definition mod for Diablo 1 has been released.](http://mod.diablo1.eu.org/)

Is it possible to play it online?

**Is it played online?**

Comment: You should check the forums @PhilippSander for more info. Link here: awake.diablo1.eu.org/bugs-and-suggestions-t526.html

Comment: I don't see why it would be possible; playing online requires Battle.NET, and that only allows you to play with stock version files.  Anything outside of that, like this mod, would either trigger an "update", or just boot you automatically.

Comment: I'd say that the answer to first question is: yes and no. Yes, you can play it online; no, you can't play it on official Battle.NET. So you will have to somehow find a way to add a server that this game would treat as Battle.NET(Closed realm). And answer to second question: you will have to search forums for that yourself.